# How to enter git repo username when `go install`-ing private packages?

Tags: git, go

I'm trying to install a package from `gitlab.company.com/package.git`, where I of course have a user, but when attempting go doesn't ask for username but instantly assumes I wish to use my linux-username (which isn't the same as the one I have on the gitlab).

Example: go.mod

```
...
require(
  ...
  gitlab.company.com/package.git
  ...
)
...
```

Bash:

`$linux-username@computer $ go install
linux-username@gitlab.company.com's password:`

Here I need to somehow use `gitlab-username@gitlab.company.com`, not `linux-username`. 
Ofc I can create a new linux user soly for syncing the project, or create a new user/alias on gitlab, so that the accounts-names match, but that just feels very hacky.

I have ssh configured and usually use that for retrieving projects from git.

Comment: You've to change your global git config while doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a linux username, it's a global git username which was set previously.

But you can set your local config in `./git/gitconfig` or using this command:

```
git config user.name "Mona Lisa"
```